# viewing files in python?

Tags: python

I am creating a sort of "Command line" in Python. I already added a few functions, such as changing login/password, executing, etc., But is it possible to browse files in the directory that the main file is in with a command/module, or will I have to make the module myself and use the import command? Same thing with changing directories to view, too.

Comment: The thing you're describing writing is normally called a "shell".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsing files is as easy as using the standard `os` module.  If you want to do something with those files, that's entirely different.

```
import os
all_files = os.listdir('.') # gets all files in current directory
```

To change directories you can issue `os.chdir('path/to/change/to')`.  In fact there are plenty of useful functions found in the `os` module that facilitate the things you're asking about.  Making them pretty and user-friendly, however, is up to you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to see someone write a a semantic file-browser, i.e. one that auto-generates tags for files according to their input and then allows views and searching accordingly.

Think about it... take an MP3, lookup the lyrics, run it through Zemanta, bam!  a PDF file, a OpenOffice file, etc., that'd be pretty kick-butt!  probably fairly intensive too, but it'd be pretty dang cool!

Cheers,
-C